# SQL Database Migration - Performance issue (Copying data from one database to another)

Tags: sql, winforms, performance, sql-server-2008, progress-bar

I have created windows application(C#.Net) to migrate data from one database to another database.
Here i select all rows of customer table from Database ABC and Insert all rows into the Dealers table of database XYZ.

My problem is that when i select top 1000 rows from table, it takes 2 mins and 35 seconds to insert these 1000 records.
but when i select top 5000 rows from table, it takes 15 mins (not 10 mins) to insert these 5000 records

Is there any way to optimize the performance so that i can insert all records/data very quickly.
(Note: Here for every record in foreach loop,i created sqlparameter and insert sql statement)

Also i have used the progress bar,but when i lose focus from my windows application,it becomes non-responsive(Not Responding as window title) and i can't see progress bar's status/progress(but process of inserting data is working in background,but not in UI).

How to solve these two problems??

Comment: Do not insert row by row, use some kind of [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Comment: @MichałPowaga i cant use BULK Insert as i have to check many condition using code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create single sql commands for hundred records and fire it, instead of single sql command for single record, this will work as bulk.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/12/05/sql-server-2008-t-sql-insert-multiple-rows.aspx

for progress bar you can use thread for updating.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951089.aspx

Comment: i can't use single sql command as i havwe to check for many conditions.i just want to know any technique to minimize this time.